# how show file-like icon for leaf nodes in jstree 3

Tags: javascript, css, jstree

I see that jstree 3 put class jstree-leaf for li element of leaf nodes(so it recognize them automatically). How can I configure types plugin to show `jstree-icon jstree-file` icon for them. is there anything like this for it:

```
'types' : {
            'file' : {
                'icon': 'jstree-icon jstree-file'
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really needing a 'file' subtype? Have you tried using 'default' instead to specify the class that you want?

```
'types' : {
            'default' : {
                'icon': 'jstree-icon jstree-file'
            }
        },
```

Comment: by doing this all icons become file-like but I want just leaf nodes become file-like

Comment: Never mind then. Have you verified if you are putting the type on your information? Let's say, your data is recovered as JSON, check if you have the attribute 'type' on it. From jsTree [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/plugins/):
"To set a node's type you can use set_type or supply a type property with the node's data."